# Can I get the credit card scanned image using card.io

Tags: card.io

I have just integrated the card.io SDK with my app, I just wanted to save scanned credit card image to show them later in my app, just like other wallet apps do. Is there any way?

Comment: Did you find a way to save the scanned image? If so please share the answer

Answer (score 5):

Josh from card.io here. [card.io is open source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source), so you could dig around and figure out how to get the image out.

However, it is hidden by default for good reasons. One is user privacy. Another is PCI compliance--the CVV2 is located on the front of AmEx cards and storing the CVV2 (anywhere, secure or not) is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but lemon.com's wallet app is showing card in deck after verifying. So, can you suggest how I can achieve behavior like that?

Comment: @FaisalBasra Lemon has a special deal with us; they're grandfathered in. I definitely understand your desire for this, and we may expose it in the future. Sorry that it is not available for you now.

Comment: Josh, is there any chance that you can actually return like the top 1/3rd of the image or so? that would be such a great addition. most of the time that is the part of the card that gives enough information about which card it is. (you may need to blur the CVV on the amex cards tho.) Thanks.

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder are there any changes according to this question: can i get scanned image?

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder Have been there any changes for this on the iOS SDK ?

Comment: @rustylepord yes, in that card.io is now open source: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source. However, for PCI and user privacy reasons you should take great care with card images. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder any updates on this? I really need to somehow validate the cardholder.

Answer (score 0):

Its not supported in the card.io code but if you really need it you can add following code in onActivityResult of CardIOActivity.java

```
        /* added image response */
        Intent origIntent = getIntent();
        Log.d(TAG, "[IMGCAP] Return image on scan request");
        if (origIntent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_RETURN_CARD_IMAGE, false)
              && mOverlay != null && mOverlay.getBitmap() != null) {

            ByteArrayOutputStream scaledCardBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d(TAG, "[IMGCAP] Attempting return of image");
            mOverlay.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, scaledCardBytes);
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_CAPTURED_CARD_IMAGE, scaledCardBytes.toByteArray());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "[IMGCAP] Set result with return image");
        /************************************/

        setResultAndFinish(resultCode, data);
```

Just before you see call to send back result of activity. You can receive in in the calling activity.
But as mentioned in above answers its not recommended to capture card image. For non financial card you can call only detect and suppress scan, you will get image for that if you enable EXTRA_RETURN_CARD_IMAGE.